# Notify vue that item internal has been changed

Tags: vue.js

Say I have some instance of class, which could be modified internal by method call (some props could be added, some removed, etc).
How could I notify vue about these changes (how to say vue “reload this item to be reactive”)?

Thanks.

PS: there are no access to vue from class (suppose it is external library)

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/h34a7s0n/50/

And possible solution:

```
// Let's say structure of 'item' is changed.
// We have to give some kick to Vue to reinitialize observer
// And yes, we need to know 'item' internals :(

// First remove old observer. 
delete this.item._data.__ob__;

// Next define the new one
Vue.util.defineReactive(this.item.__ob__.value, '_data', this.item._data);

// And finally notify about changes, like $set does
this.item.__ob__.dep.notify();
```

Yes, it is dirty. But it works: https://jsfiddle.net/h34a7s0n/89/

Is there any clean way to solve?

Comment: Want to explain about "class, which could be modified internal by method call". It means that class has no depends on Vue (so it is not possible to modify class to use `$set` inside or something else related to Vue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `v2` property of `_data`. `v2`, specifically, is not reactive.

Official docs - [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of `Object.observe`), Vue **cannot detect property addition or deletion**.

To work around it, you can either declare it in the constructor (this option works best when you know what properties you'll have):

```js
  constructor(v1) {
    this._data = {
      v1,
      v2: null  // <========= added this
    };
  }
```

```js
class C {
  constructor(v1) {
    this._data = {
      v1,
      v2: null  // <========= added this
    };
  }

  addV2(v2) {
    this._data['v2'] = v2;
    alert( 'Item is fully loaded' );
    console.log(this._data);
  }

  get value1() {
    return this._data.v1;
  }

  get value2() {
    if ('v2' in this._data) {
      return this._data.v2;
    }

    return;
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
     <div>
            {{item.value1}}, {{item.value2}}
            <button @click="fullLoad">+</button>
        </div>
  </div>`,
  data: {
    item: new C(0)
  },
  methods: {
    fullLoad() {
      this.item.addV2(2 * Math.random());
      
      // How to notify vue about changes here?
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Or change it using `Vue.set()`. (This option works best for the general case.)

```js
  addV2(v2) {
    Vue.set(this._data, 'v2', v2);    // <========= changed here
    alert( 'Item is fully loaded' );
    console.log(this._data);
  }
```

```js
class C {
  constructor(v1) {
    this._data = {
      v1
    };
  }

  addV2(v2) {
    Vue.set(this._data, 'v2', v2);    // <========= changed here
    alert( 'Item is fully loaded' );
    console.log(this._data);
  }

  get value1() {
    return this._data.v1;
  }

  get value2() {
    if ('v2' in this._data) {
      return this._data.v2;
    }

    return;
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
     <div>
            {{item.value1}}, {{item.value2}}
            <button @click="fullLoad">+</button>
        </div>
  </div>`,
  data: {
    item: new C(0)
  },
  methods: {
    fullLoad() {
      this.item.addV2(2 * Math.random());
      
      // How to notify vue about changes here?
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

## No access to the third-party class code

If you have no access to `C` class internals, you can re-add the `item` data property, as below:

```js
  methods: {
    fullLoad() {
      let i = this.item;                                  // save for reinsertion
      this.item = null;                                   // remove
      Vue.set(this, 'item', i);                           // reinsert as fully reactive
      
      this.item.addV2(2 * Math.random());
    }
  }
```

Runnable demo:

```js
class C {
  constructor(v1) {
    this._data = {
      v1
    };
  }

  addV2(v2) {
    this._data['v2'] = v2;
    alert( 'Item is fully loaded' );
    console.log(this._data);
  }

  get value1() {
    return this._data.v1;
  }

  get value2() {
    if ('v2' in this._data) {
      return this._data.v2;
    }

    return;
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
     <div>
            {{item.value1}}, {{item.value2}}
            <button @click="fullLoad">+</button>
        </div>
  </div>`,
  data: {
    item: new C(0)
  },
  methods: {
    fullLoad() {
      let i = this.item;                                  // save for reinsertion
      this.item = null;                                   // remove
      Vue.set(this, 'item', i);                           // reinsert as fully reactive
      
      this.item.addV2(2 * Math.random());
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sure, I read docs.
The problem is, that `class C` could be any 3rd party library, that' why I asked about "class, which could be modified internal by method call".
I mean, when you call some method on class instance, then it could change props inside it.
So, I don't have access to class constructor or internal behaviour, I use public interface for `class C`

Comment: Well, then, you could use `Vue.set(this.item, '_data', {...this.item._data});` right before calling `this.item.addV2()`, which is outside `C` class.

Comment: Hey, I think I've come up with something simple and effective. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Looks good enough for me. But need attention in template: v-if="item" should be used. Thanks